# How to write this query using left outer join instead not in

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me writing below code using left outer join instead of not in

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.NUM = B.NUM                          
WHERE (A.XX <> '') 
  AND (A.ID = 'MM') 
  AND A.XX NOT IN (SELECT NUM    
                   FROM A   
                   WHERE ID = 'YY')
  and (A.XX  <> '') 
  AND (A.ID = 'MM') 
  AND (A.XX) NOT IN (SELECT NUM    
                     FROM C   
                     WHERE ID = 'YY')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a left join and check that the joined table is null (meaning that no matching row has been found).

This query is going to return the same data than your original query, without using NOT IN operators :

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
     INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND  A.NUM = B.NUM
     LEFT JOIN A2 ON A2.ID = 'YY' AND A2.NUM = A.XX
     LEFT JOIN C  ON C.ID =  'YY' AND C.NUM = A.XX
WHERE A.XX <> '' AND A.ID = 'MM' AND A2.NUM IS NULL AND
      A.XX <> '' AND A.ID = 'MM' AND C.NUM IS NULL
```